# Start Time Flip HubTile Telerik Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, telerik

Can I edit the when the start time of flip from hubtile? I have 2 hubtile and it flip together. I do want the hubtiles flip not in the same time. I already try manipulate it using UpdateInterval but it doesn't satisfy me because some time it will flip together again. Any solutions?

This is my xaml code. In cs I did nothing

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadCustomHubTile Width="198" Height="193" Margin="18,117,240,372" x:Name="NabiHome" UpdateInterval="0:0:2" Tap="NabiHome_Tap">
                <telerikPrimitives:RadCustomHubTile.FrontContent>
                    <Image Source="/Images/Button/25 Nabi.png"></Image>
                </telerikPrimitives:RadCustomHubTile.FrontContent>
                <telerikPrimitives:RadCustomHubTile.BackContent>
                    <Image Source="/Images/Button/25 Nabi.png"></Image>
                </telerikPrimitives:RadCustomHubTile.BackContent>
            </telerikPrimitives:RadCustomHubTile>
            <telerikPrimitives:RadCustomHubTile Width="198" Height="193" Margin="241,320,17,169" UpdateInterval="0:0:3" x:Name="Quiz" Tap="Quiz_Tap">
                <telerikPrimitives:RadCustomHubTile.FrontContent>
                    <Image Source="/Images/Button/Quiz.png"></Image>
                </telerikPrimitives:RadCustomHubTile.FrontContent>
                <telerikPrimitives:RadCustomHubTile.BackContent>
                    <Image Source="/Images/Button/Quiz.png"></Image>
                </telerikPrimitives:RadCustomHubTile.BackContent>
            </telerikPrimitives:RadCustomHubTile>
```

Comment: You have to post code. You can't honestly expect anyone to find a solution to your problem just from your description